# Including a top level element with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a POJO like this

```
public class Pojo {
    ...
    public static String toJson(ArrayList<Pojo> pojos) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(pojos);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[
  {  
    "arrival": "19:12:30",
    "typeOfDay": "regular",
    "stopCode": "CMPZ",
    "route": "B",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "arrival": "19:13:30",
    "typeOfDay": "regular",
    "stopCode": "AVSV",
    "route": "B",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

But what I want is this:

```
{
  "pojos": [
   {  
     "arrival": "19:12:30",
     "typeOfDay": "regular",
     "stopCode": "CMPZ",
     "route": "B",
     "id": 1
   },
   {
     "arrival": "19:13:30",
     "typeOfDay": "regular",
     "stopCode": "AVSV",
     "route": "B",
     "id": 2
   }
  ]
}
```

How I can do it? I'm using Gson 2.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method like this:

```
 public static String toJson(List<Pojo> pojos) {
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      Map m = new TreeMap();
      m.put("pojos", pojos);
      return gson.toJson(m);
  }
```

BTW, note that I changed signature, prefer an interface (`List`) instead of an implementation (`ArrayList`) into your methods.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea what Gson is, but I imagine something like this would work...

```
    return gson.toJson({pojos:pojos});
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Java, I think that would not work.